# How can I search an Excel spreadsheet in SharePoint?

Tags: excel, mobile, sharepoint-onlineapp

Looking to be able to search an Excel spreadsheet from the SharePoint mobile app.

I have a spreadsheet with Postal Codes/Zip Codes with corresponding information. I would like to be able to search as you would in Excel.

When I upload a test spreadsheet, it opens as like a PDF. User has "Read" permissions for the document library the spreadsheet is located in.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For clarity, are you wanting to use SharePoint search or are you wanting to do a basic CTRL + F to search within an open Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint search will direct you to the Excel file, but it will not direct you to any specific row or column in the Excel file.  Assuming that you want to be directed to the row or column, you would need to put the excel data into a SharePoint List for that to happen.