# How do I view a list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

In answer to my question

[How can I search an Excel spreadsheet in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275009/how-can-i-search-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint)

Josh McClanahan posted an answer which worked for me but as I signed in as a guest I cannot mark it as answered, thank you Josh!!! (Admins could you mark his answer please as I dont have enough reputation)

I now have my list which works brilliantly on the Mobile App under the List section however, I cannot find it on the Web Page version!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find all the lists in your site on the Site contents page `_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14`.

You can also display the list on the Quick Launch menu via List settings > List name, description and navigation and set "Display this list on the Quick Launch?" to "Yes".

References:

[SharePoint site contents page.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-site-contents-page-ba495c1e-00f4-475d-97c7-b518d546566b)

[Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Comment: Thank you, always better to ask an expert I think!

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to site contents which you will see on the left hand navigation. In there you may start searching for your list or it will be shown. Please let me know if you need further clarification.
Make sure where the list is created, subsite or top site?
Please try googling to find your answer, since it is very basic and you will find a lot of info on the web.