# List Limit 5000 Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, mobile-view

I have a list that is 12488 items in size that with your kind help I have uploaded to SharePoint Online (below post).

[How do I view a list in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276453/how-do-i-view-a-list-in-sharepoint)

I need SharePoint mobile app users to be able to access this to see if a certain item/customer is "yes" or "no".

Unfortunatley the "yes" (ok to proceed with work) is almost 4800 of the total items so even if I remove the "no" (do not proceed with work) and upload this to SharePoint Online, it wont be long before that exceeds the 5000 limit.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59) article. Add indexing on the Yes/No column. try to use folder structure if possible. Also create filtered views based on column conditions (maybe filters on multiple columns to limit the item count less than 5000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the list items into two views with the below condition :

1. With "Yes" condition and created or modified columns

   2. With "No" condition and created or modified columns

Or split even with more views depends on the various metadata and their frequency of updates.

View filter logic should be something like below :

1. For view 1:

Column 1 eq "Yes"  and created >= [today] - 3

2. For view 2:

Column 1 eq "No"  and created >= [today] -3

Notes :

- In the above filter displaying data which were created for the last 3 days with yes and no values. This is just for example, you can change it as per your requirements.

And so on....

The bottom line of the above approach is, at any given point of time view will have less items (less than 5k).

For details implementation please refer the below article :

[List view threshold error(5000 items issue) in SharePoint On-Premise/SharePoint Online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/sharepoint-listview-threshold-error-5000-items-issue/)

Comment: Tried this with an additional filter (lets call it A) with just the "yes" items and down to 2827 now so will will hopefully delay the inevitable 5000 items for a while. This isn't as elegant as I hoped as will now have an A/yes, B/yes, C/yes, D/yes etc list so multiple places to check but I suppose if it works then great! Just have to deal with the Mobile Users moaning about picking which list to search in! Thanks Ganesh and SP Expert!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the long term solution could be to set up a flow or timer job to trim the listitems, either deleting the old entries or migrating them to an archive of sorts